# To assign different tooltip for different images

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have array of images(Dogs), which i am displaying like this:

[image]

I am trying to assign different names different dogs using **tooltip**.Means for **dog1: tooltip(dog1), dog2: tooltip(dog2)....and so on**.in my example every tooltip is displaying for same dog as in the image. What i am missing:

Stackblitz **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-list-option-new-npahcd?file=app/selection-list/selection-list.component.html)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using index, you can get the particular tooltip text.

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let dog of dogs">

            <div class="section">
                <p id="name">Dogs:</p>
                <img  matTooltip="{{dog.tooltip[i]}}"  *ngFor="let image of dog.img; let i = index;" class="dog-img"  src="{{image }}" >
            </div>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update you code as below:

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let dog of dogs">

            <div class="section">
                <p id="name">Dogs:</p>
                <span *ngFor="let image of dog.img ; let dataRowIndex = index">
                <img  matTooltip="{{dog.tooltip[dataRowIndex]}}"   class="dog-img"  src="{{image }}" >
            </span>
            </div>


    </div>
```

[Updated stackblitz **Demo**:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-list-option-new-q3hpce?file=app/selection-list/selection-list.component.html)